# How do I find a coordinate using cartesian coordinate system with just an index?

Tags: python, math

How do I find a coordinate using cartesian coordinate system with just an index?

- For instance, 4 points to 1,2 and 9 points to 1,3.
- Assume that the blocks will always wrap around 1,1.

I'm not married to the order of the grid, but I want to call the location by an index rather then a coronate if at all possible.

I'm trying to create a grid for game tiles.

[image]

Comment: "with just an index" to what? is this homework?

Comment: I think you need to clarify how the index maps to the coordinates. For example, using the two cases you have given the coordinates could be `(1, sqrt(index))` - but I doubt this is the case.

Comment: Oh, and this does sound like a homework problem. You'd be best off giving the full problem, what you've tried so far, and a specific question (or questions) rather than trying to get someone else to do the whole thing for you.

Comment: Not a homework problem, but if you know where I can read up on this I would love to have that reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're loking for is what's known as a [pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), where *(x, y)* maps to a certain integer *N* and vice-versa (the function is one-to-one and onto). Keith's first answer (for finite ranges) is close, but requires you to know the maximum size of the square, in effect adding another parameter to the pairing function. His screenshot in Excel (for infinite ranges) shows how it's done, but I'd like to add some explanation to it.

Given a value *N* that you want to map to a coordinate *(x, y)*:

First, we locate which ***layer*** it belongs to. A layer is what Keith showed in his **Excel column D**, and goes something like this:

```
 1  2  5 10    ->    '1  2  3  4
 4  3  6 11    ->     2 '2  3  4
 9  8  7 12    ->     3  3 '3  4
16 15 14 13    ->     4  4  4 '4
```

You find out what layer *N* belongs to by

```
layer = math.floor(math.sqrt(N - 1)) + 1
```

Given the layer, find the integer corresponding to the ***diagonal*** (shown above with a ', with values 1, 3, 7, 13 for layers 1, 2, 3, 4; **Column H** in Keith's answer)

```
diagonal = (layer^2) - layer + 1
```

Now that you have the diagonal, we can find the values of *x* and *y* (Keith's **columns I and J**):

```
if (N < diagonal):   
    x = layer
    y = N - ((layer-1)^2) + 1  
elif (N == diagonal):
    x = layer
    y = layer
else:
    x = (layer^2) - N + 1
    y = layer
```

My formulas look a little different from Keith's, but they're ultimately derived from the same place. I did my calculations independently, then compared them to Keith's, and found that they're pretty much identical.

Comment: I gave you the check because you were able to give me context to learn more on. I was having trouble trying to figure out what I needed to research to make this happen. If I could afford two checks, Keith would have had the second.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the coordinates are:

- Purely integer
- Finite, say in a square of dimension 'N'.

Then

```
 (x,y) -> x + N*y
   n -> (x,y) = (n%N,  n/N)
```

See also: [this wikipedia picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pairing_natural.svg) for a way of handling non-finite ranges.
Here is an Excel image [image: Excel]. Excel is quite a nice tool for prototyping a calculation. you can see at a glance each step of the computation.

Obviously, you can map this into code very easily; it handle the infinite quarter grid case.

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit more for me? I'm pretty sure this is the solution but it's been a while since I've gotten down and dirty with math.

Comment: @jbcurtin - The picture you have has a strange arrangement in terms of mapping integers to cells, is this for a reason?

Comment: No reason, I'm open to an adjustment. I took a look at the photo you posted and it seemed like what I needed; but again I'm having trouble figuring were to plug into your answer. Can you provide me with a wiki link? To both finite and non-finite?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm reading too little into this, but what is wrong with a dictionary of tuples where the key is the index, and the tuple contains the coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

Making some assumptions here, but you could solve these as linear equations:

```
9 = 1x + 3y
4 = 1x + 2y
-----------
5 = 0x + 1y

->  5 = y
-> -6 = x, by plugging y back into one of the two linear equations
```

Now you that you have `(x, y)`, you can translate any coordinate pair `(x', y')` into an index:

```
newIndex = -6x' + 5y
```

If you need to wrap around, use a modulus.

Comment: If the individual indexes were on a line, linear equations would be useful. However, that's not the case.